# JavaScript: Validate form all at once

Tags: javascript, validation

When my script validates a filled out form, it will check for errors one at a time rather than for all the errors all at once. I know this is because I'm using `if` statements which will obviously stop when an argument validates as `True`.

How do I adapt my script so that it will show the end-user all the errors in one go? Do I use the `continue` statement? Or is there a better way?

```
function checkForm() {
            if (!retext.test(document.myform.sport.value)) {
                document.myform.textfield.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Invalid text.";
                document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }

            else if (!re.test(document.myform.email.value)) {
                document.myform.email.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("emailwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid email.";
                document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }

            else if (!retel.test(document.myform.tel.value)) {
                document.myform.tel.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("telwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid telephone number.";
                document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
        }

<form name="myform" method="POST" action="http://youtube.com" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Hi</legend>
            <label>Random text: </label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield">
            <div id="text"></div>
            <label>Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <div id="emailwarn"></div>
            <label>Tel: </label>
            <input type="tel" name="tel" maxlength="11">
            <div id="telwarn"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `checkForm` function run all of the checks, and only have one return (at the end).

eg.

```
function checkForm() {
    var valid = true;

    if (!retext.test(document.myform.sport.value)) {
        document.myform.textfield.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Invalid text.";
        document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    }

    if (!re.test(document.myform.email.value)) {
        document.myform.email.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("emailwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid email.";
        document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    }

    if (!retel.test(document.myform.tel.value)) {
        document.myform.tel.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
        document.getElementById("telwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid telephone number.";
        document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Do you use `if` on all of them, or do you use `else if`?

Comment: If you use `else`, only the first one to be "activated" (found invalid) will run. If you want them to all be independent, and potentially all run, just use `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Set a return value and return it at the end.

```
function checkForm() {
        var valid = true;
        if (!testcondition) {
            // do stuff
            valid = false;
        }

        if (!othertestcondition) {
            // do stuff
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkForm() {
    var ok = true;
            if (!retext.test(document.myform.sport.value)) {
                document.myform.textfield.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Invalid text.";
                document.getElementById("text").style.display = "block";
                ok =false;
            }

            if (!re.test(document.myform.email.value)) {
                document.myform.email.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("emailwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid email.";
                document.getElementById("emailwarn").style.display = "block";
                ok =false;
            }

            if (!retel.test(document.myform.tel.value)) {
                document.myform.tel.style.border = "3.5px solid red";
                document.getElementById("telwarn").innerHTML = "Invalid telephone number.";
                document.getElementById("telwarn").style.display = "block";
                ok = false;
            }
            return ok;
        }
```